# Get number of line recursively

Tags: python, python-2.7

There's a file named 1.feature:

```
background

Scenario:1
Scenario:2
Scenario:3
Scenario:4
aasdf;
ad;das
dasd;asd
ad'asd
tekst
asdsadsa
Scenario
tekst
tekst
tekst
asdasd
```

I'd like to get line numbers of last 'Scenario' after which appears 'text' text.
In this particular example it would be: line no 6 and 13.

Right now I have such code:

```
with open('1.feature', 'r') as feat:
    tabula = feat.readlines()
    for element in tabula:
        if 'tekst' in element:
            current_index = tabula.index(element)
for element in tabula:
    if 'Scenario' in element and current_index > tabula.index(element):
        scenario_begining = '1.feature:' + str(tabula.index(element) + 1)
print scenario_begining
```

Expected output:

```
1.feature:6
1.feature:13
```

Current output:

```
1.feature:6
```

I suppose that the problem is with current_index variable.

Maybe there's any easier way to get such output?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the requirements, when a "Scenario" is hit, the position of that scenario is stored. In the case where the desired text is found and the scenario has not already been printed, the scenario is printed:

```
text = 'tekst'

with open('1.feature', 'r') as feat:
    tabula = feat.readlines()

current_scenario = -1
for i in range(len(tabula)):
    if 'Scenario' in tabula[i]:
        current_scenario = i+1
    elif tabula[i].strip('\n') == text and current_scenario != -1:
        print '1.feature:', current_scenario
        current_scenario = -1
```

The result is:

```
1.feature:6
1.feature:13
```

Comment: Not exactely. Let me precise. If in file we got 'text' it means that we're looking for the nearest 'Scenario' before 'text'. If there's more than one 'Scenario' before particular 'text' we get only the closest 'Scenario' before.